# Create an If Statement which uses 2 criteria to sort serial numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm currently beginning a Javascript coding course. One task requires me to check if a serial number is valid, and if it is, add it to an array to store all valid serial numbers.

The serial numbers must be:

- odd numbers
- contain 6 digits

Here is my current code:

```
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
  console.log(serialNumbers);
  const efficientSerialNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < serialNumbers.length; i++) {
    let currentNumber = serialNumbers[i]
    if (currentNumber % 2 === 1 && currentNumber.length === 6) {
      efficientSerialNumbers.push(currentNumber)
    }
  };
  return efficientSerialNumbers;
}
```

According to the platform, this code is not removing the even numbers, error message below:

> 'should keep all efficient numbers - those that are odd and have six
> digits in
>
> ✕ AssertionError: expected [] to deeply equal [ 234567, 456789 ]
>
> logs
>
> [ 123456, 234567, 345678, 456789 ]'

Have tried as above, as well as nested If statements

Answer (score 1):

This will always be `false` for numeric values:

```
currentNumber.length === 6
```

Because numbers don't have a `length` property, so that value is `undefined`.

You can convert the number to a string first:

```
currentNumber.toString().length === 6
```

Or, as pointed out [in a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77970542/create-an-if-statement-which-uses-2-criteria-to-sort-serial-numbers-in-javascrip#comment137458152_77970577), you could check the value of the number against upper and lower bounds:

```
currentNumber > 99999 && currentNumber < 1000000
```

(For large sets this could potentially have a performance improvement as well.  For small sets it's more a matter of personal preference.)

For example:

```js
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
  console.log(serialNumbers);
  const efficientSerialNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < serialNumbers.length; i++) {
    let currentNumber = serialNumbers[i]
    if (currentNumber % 2 === 1 && currentNumber.toString().length === 6) {
      efficientSerialNumbers.push(currentNumber)
    }
  };
  return efficientSerialNumbers;
}

console.log(findEfficientBulbs([ 123456, 234567, 345678, 456789 ]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This doesn't seem to have solved my problem,  my original code was passing 4 of the 5 criteria on the platform:

4 Passing
1 Failing

should return an array

logs

[ 123123 ]

should discard serial numbers with five or fewer figures

logs

[ 1, 123, 12345 ]

should discard serial numbers with seven or more figures

logs

[ 1234567, 123456789 ]

should discard even numbers

logs

[ 1234, 123456, 12345678 ]

should keep all efficient numbers

  ✕ AssertionError: expected [] to deeply equal [ 234567, 456789 ]

Comment: @MartinGrennan: I've updated the answer to include a runnable code snippet demonstrating the functionality, in which you can see that the input `[ 123456, 234567, 345678, 456789 ]` produces the result `[ 234567, 456789 ]`.  Please indicate what specifically isn't working as expected in that example.

Comment: Even with your edit, it still seems to be adding serial numbers which are even and 6 digits long

Comment: Another way to check for 6 digits is `currentNumber > 99999 && currentNumber < 1000000`

Comment: @MartinGrennan: How are you reaching that conclusion?  The output is demonstrably `[ 234567, 456789 ]`.  Which of those numbers do you think is "even"?  Are you instead referring to the `console.log` statement you have in your function?

Comment: @David that seems to have solved it when I copy and paste your runnable code snippet, not sure why it wasn't working before.

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Simpler

```js
const findEfficientBulbs = (serialNumbers) => serialNumbers
  .filter(num => num % 2 === 1 && num >= 100000 && num <= 999999);

console.log(findEfficientBulbs([123456, 234567, 345678, 456789]));
```